# How do you paint from screen touch events (at scale) using Jetpack Compose on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose, android-graphics

There are only a couple of guides to using screen touch events (or MotionEvents) for painting on a screen using Jetpack Compose. All the guides I have found involve:

1. linking a touch event to a Jetpack Compose `State` so a recomposition is triggered on every new touch action (a bit like calling `invalidate()` in the old view-based Android approach);
2. saving that event  change to a remembered list;
3. and then redrawing the *entire list* on every recomposition.

The best guide I have found is this one: [Code Simple Android Jetpack Compose Drawing App](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/code-simple-android-jetpack-compose-drawing-app-886d1146ad20) which has complete code [here](https://github.com/elye/demo_android_jetpack_compose_drawing_app/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/jcdrawing/JcDrawActivity.kt).

With only a few hundred touch events, the algorithm is surprisingly responsive. But when there are thousands of events in the list, it starts to get a bit like [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm), and gets slower and slower until it eventually stops working.

In the old Kotlin/Android, the way around that would typically be to paint to a [Canvas that is backed by a bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#Canvas(android.graphics.Bitmap)), so you don't need to redraw the entire screen on each `invalidate()`. But I can't find a Canvas in Jetpack Compose that seamlessly saves to a bitmap.

Is there a way in Jetpack Compose to simply `remember` the contents of a Composable Canvas, so the entire Canvas doesn't need to be redrawn on each recomposition?

Failing that, is there a way to back a Jetpack Compose Canvas with a bitmap, like you can in the old Canvas?

As far as I can tell, the [Jetpack Compose Painter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/painter/package-summary) object is what we are supposed to use for this, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

In the Painter() object I can't work out how to access a `drawScope` in which to issue dynamic Compose commands like `drawLine` and `drawCircle`. All I can find is where you can override `drawScope.onDraw()`, but I don't know how to use that for what I want.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be terrific!

Comment: I'd question why you're using Compose for this.  It seems it isn't a suitable technology for your usecase. Just use views.

Comment: You could've split the points in chunks and draw each chunk in a separate `Canvas` all placed in a `Box`. Compose shouldn't recompose/redraw the views which parameters haven't changed, but it's not gonna work until [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199496149) is fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Philip, what's the overhead associated with adding a new Canvas? Say I had a new canvas for every complete stroke (DOWN - MOVE - MOVE - MOVE - UP) I could potentially have many thousands of Canvas functions in the one Box, all listening for their parameter change. Would that get janky and/or inelegant at some point? Not to mention, very long strokes would also get janky at some point, and the alternative - using multiple Canvases for one stroke - would be a *nightmare* from a bezier curve smoothing perspective, no? There is no bitmap solution?